# Знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

"Что бы ты ни делал — все бесполезно" — правильно ли поставлено тире?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предложение сложноподчиненное,по основному правилу нужна запятая. Но при интонационном выделении придаточное изъяснительное, уступительное и условное могут выделяться тире.

Comment: Добавлю: когда придаточное предложение стоит перед главным